# How do I allow to select the "Match All" or "Match Any" filter?

Tags: views

I have a Drupal 7 View with BEF and 7 exposed filters.
I want to show a Radio Button below the filter with 2 options "Match All" and "Match Any".

By default the "Match Any" option will be selected and if the user selects any filter the result will be shown for the matching filters.
But if the user selects "Match All" then the result should show only the records where all the selected filters match.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please try to put your question in a question form, like "how to ... ?" or "why is ... happening?"